# mininet-wifi error:'Mininet' object has no attribute 'addBaseStation'

Tags: python, mininet

When I execute my Python script using mininet-wifi, I am getting the following error, and I don't know why?

```
error:'Mininet' object has no attribute 'addBaseStation'
```

Should I change `addBaseStation` into `addAcessPoint`? If so, what is the difference between these?

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You get the error because `Mininet` instances have no `addBaseStation()` method. They have `addStation()` and `addPhysicalBaseStation()` methods though. According to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try out addAccessPoint() instead.